# Why can't list the files ending with tmp?

Tags: files

The are four files ending with tmp in my Desktop directory.

[image]

Why can't I list them?

```
ls -al  |rg  tmp
#nothing as output
debian@debian:~/Desktop$ ls -al  lu12761y6p7ro.tmp
ls: cannot access 'lu12761y6p7ro.tmp': No such file or directory
```

I am sure it is `lu12761y6p7ro.tmp`.

[image]

`rg` is the `ripgrep`.

```
ls -ld lu1276* 
ls: cannot access 'lu1276*': No such file or directory
```

Strange:all the file ending with tmp vanished after reboot.

Comment: what is this `rg`? what is the output of `ls -ld lu100*` for example

Comment: ls -ld lu100*
ls: cannot access 'lu100*': No such file or directory

Comment: I think a better test command would be `ls -ld *tmp*`

Comment: I believe, you are misunderstanding what `rg` does. `rg` does **not** search the file path strings for your pattern, but the files **within** the paths you provide. It is - if I read `man rg` correctly - basically `grep -rl PATTERN DIR`.

Comment: @FelixJN Note that the user is using the tool on the output of `ls`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have seen that, however, `man rg` is a bit confusingly worded and makes it easy to misunderstand - it often uses something along the lines of *searching directories* instead of *files **in** directories*. I still believe that `ls | rg` will search the files/dirs `ls` provides rather than the output text itself. ... at least that is my understanding of the manual, but I might be mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

Most Desktop Environments(DE) create 'fake' file & folder icons on the desktop.  It is common to have, for example a "Trash" icon and perhaps a "Home" icon which appear and act similar to folders, but have no presence as a file in ~/Desktop directory. It is quite likely that your *.tmp files are merely part of your DE.  You should examine your DE settings in detail, and also try examining these 'files' using the DE tools (perhaps a right click to show properties).

Comment: In the first picture, the files are visible within File Explorer; I have never heard of File Explorer showing "fake" files, and that would be a weird behaviour indeed.

Comment: "File Explorer" is a MS Windows tool, and I find no evidence of a linux tool by that name.    The 'ls' can't see the files and that your mystery gui tool can, strongly suggests they are an artifact of your gui tool.